# Quarkus native image on linux with Docker Desktop: JVMCIError AccessDeniedException

Tags: java, linux, docker, quarkus, quarkus-native

[Cross post](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/37193).

I'm new to Quarkus, and just checked out the [sample application](https://quarkus.io/get-started/). That works fine, so I now want to try a [native build](https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image#container-runtime) using the provided containers.

I'm running Docker Desktop 4.23.0 on Ubuntu 23.10, and I verified my home directory is share with DD:

[image]

When attempting `./mvnw install -Dnative -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true -Dquarkus.native.container-runtime=docker`:

```
Build resources:
 - 5.80GB of memory (75.6% of 7.67GB system memory, determined at start)
 - 10 thread(s) (100.0% of 10 available processor(s), determined at start)
[2/8] Performing analysis...  [*****]                                                                   (17.5s @ 1.18GB)
   10,678 reachable types   (85.9% of   12,426 total)
   15,175 reachable fields  (56.7% of   26,771 total)
   53,763 reachable methods (55.8% of   96,362 total)
    3,437 types,   104 fields, and 3,151 methods registered for reflection
       61 types,    59 fields, and    55 methods registered for JNI access
        4 native libraries: dl, pthread, rt, z
[3/8] Building universe...                                                                               (3.0s @ 0.91GB)
[4/8] Parsing methods...      [**]                                                                       (2.1s @ 1.07GB)
[5/8] Inlining methods...     [***]                                                                      (1.4s @ 1.17GB)
[6/8] Compiling methods...    [****]                                                                    (14.1s @ 1.19GB)
[7/8] Layouting methods...    [**]                                                                       (2.7s @ 1.82GB)

[8/8] Creating image...       [**]                                                                       (0.0s @ 2.28GB)
Fatal error: jdk.vm.ci.common.JVMCIError: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /project/svm_err_b_20231118T013054.112_pid81.md
    at jdk.internal.vm.ci/jdk.vm.ci.common.JVMCIError.shouldNotReachHere(JVMCIError.java:52)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.reports.ReportUtils.reportImpl(ReportUtils.java:174)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.reports.ReportUtils.report(ReportUtils.java:155)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.ProgressReporter.printEpilog(ProgressReporter.java:652)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.reportEpilog(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:604)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:596)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:720)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.start(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:142)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:97)
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /project/svm_err_b_20231118T013054.112_pid81.md
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:261)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:379)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createFile(Files.java:657)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.reports.ReportUtils.reportImpl(ReportUtils.java:164)
    ... 7 more
```

Considering I'm just following the tutorials, this is either a bug or I'm missing something obvious. Help is appreciated.

```
$ uname -a 
Linux jm 6.5.0-10-generic #10-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Oct 13 13:49:38 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ java -version
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Oracle GraalVM 21.0.1+12.1 (build 21.0.1+12-jvmci-23.1-b19, mixed mode, sharing)

$ mvnw --version
Apache Maven 3.9.5 (57804ffe001d7215b5e7bcb531cf83df38f93546)
```

Comment: This turns out to be an issue with how Quarkus instructs docker to setup the user in the container and how Docker Desktop binds mounts.

Fixed in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/37242

Comment: Indeed!  Wow, they are quick to fix. Amazing turnaround.